# Autofill SMS verification code for Android browser using JavaScript/PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, one-time-password

I'm trying to autofill SMS verification codes (OTP) on my site on Android browsers, giving a simple HTML tag `autocomplete=one-time-code` work on iOS devices but on Android, it doesn't work.

There are two alternatives for Android: SMS Retriever API, and SMS User Consent API, but none of them has JavaScript/PHP/HTML code guide inside them. Also, the first one needs to have a hash code at the end and the second one needs to accept access Messages to read the SMS code.

There is another API named WebOTP API which has the codes for Javascript/PHP/HTML. However, your SMS message needs to be in a specific format and have @yoursite in it to be able to work even you need to give permission to read SMS when asked to get this work.

None of these three APIs is a one-tap automated autofill OTP on an Android web browser.

I just tried myself OTP on gmail.com using my relative's Android phone with my SIM card inserted to login to my Gmail, it sends you a simple 6-digit code without any hash at the end, asking permission to access Messages and it's a fully one-tap automated login.

I need to set up exactly like this on my site for Android devices.

Comment: You mentioned WebOTP, and that really seems like the way to go. https://web.dev/web-otp/ and https://web.dev/sms-otp-form/ cover it. The videos appear to be one-tap on Android, too.